# How to create a setup file to install MVC .net web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation, web-deployment

I have MVC2.0 web application and I need to make an exe installer to deploy the application and the DB on the customer's server.

Is there a tool in VS2010 to do this or do I have to use a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create deployment package, bin deploy or simply use publish option to drop files to web server.

Here are some useful links:

- [Bin Deployment](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx)
- [VS 2010 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)
- [Package, One click deploy](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article997-vs-2010-deployment-package-one-click-deploy-and-webconfig-transformation-.aspx)
- [Automating Deployment with Microsoft Web Deploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx)

Comment: I need to have an exe or msi file .. and the customer can dbl click then next next .. and application and db is installed on server and running

Comment: Than try creating deployment package it creates .cmd file that installs your app.

Comment: As far as I know, NuGet can't be used for web app deployment. I've added more links on web deployment.