# What does someone mean by deploying an ASP.Net MVC application as binaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have been developing an MVC application for a client, he's gone away and has asked his PM to ask me to release the application to his team as a set of binaries. Now my understanding is that whilst I could publish from Visual Studio and hand that over I would still be releasing source code given that the razor views are dynamically compiled.

What would you expect if you had asked for the application as binaries?

Comment: But still don't you need provide views(.cshtml) code to your client?

Comment: binaries is the non human readable code that the machine will run. It is essentially what you get after compiling.

Comment: You'll have to provide the published source code in the form of .dll's and the cshtml views to his team

Comment: This is probably an example of Chinese Whispers between the client and PM. The PM probably isn't technical and only remembers the word binaries from the conversation. You should hand over all that is needed to deploy the site (i.e. binaries, views, web.config etc)

Comment: You can [compile your views though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Thanks guys, I need to get face to face with the client and not the PM and understand what he's expecting. Thanks also @CodeCaster wasn't aware I could compile views!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with Jumpingcode, sounds like the classic PM not being technical and the conversation being lost in translation.

Only second guessing here, but they could be looking for a MSI (or equivalent) installer for the web app... see this other stack overflow question [How to create a setup file to install MVC .net web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323631/how-to-create-a-setup-file-to-install-mvc-net-web-application)